# How does the judge function work?

Tags: pokemon-lets-go

At a certain point in the game, you can unlock the judge function, to see the potential of your Pokémon. I assume this are the IV stats within this game, opposed to the the [AV](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/341145/80141) already explained. What are the different textual values representing, in both upper corners?

[image: screenshot with judge function]

Comment: I'm assuming you bought the pokeball accessory? Because if not, I'm about to go fire up up a question about Mew....

Comment: @Ellesedil I did. Bought the whole bundle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This page is indeed a replica of the similar looking screen introduced in Sun and Moon to display IVs.

The text on the right describes how good the particular stats are:

- 31 - Best
- 30 - Fantastic
- 26-29 - Very Good
- 16-25 - Pretty Good
- 1-15 - Decent
- 0 - No Good

And the text on the left is for the overall total:

- 151-186 - Amazing Stats
- 121-150 - Great Stats
- 91-120 - Good Stats
- 0-90 - OK Stats

You can unlock this judge by talking to Professor Oak's Aide in the gate between routes 11 and 12.

You don't see it in yours, but usually you also get one stat name highlighted in blue and another in red -- this indicates the Pokémon's nature, with red being the raised stat and blue being the lowered stat (both by 10%). If your nature raises and lowers your same stat (also known as a "neutral nature"), none of them will be colored.

Source: [Serebii](https://www.serebii.net/letsgopikachueevee/useful.shtml)

Comment: While is true, the Let's Go series was also designed to bring in people who've never played Pokémon. Newer trainers may not necessarily know that. Just my 2 cents :)

Comment: I haven't played since gen 2, so the color thing info is helpful.  :)

Comment: In the question's screenshot, the text around the graph lists "good" for special defense. But, this answer doesn't seem to show what the stat value range should be for just "good". Is "good" instead "very good" or "pretty good"? Or even "decent"? Mew's attack is also listed as "OK". Which one is "OK" supposed to be?

Comment: @Ellesedil It can also be confusing for Westerners, since in this case _red_ indicates the "good" stat, and _blue_ indicates the "bad" stat—took me a while to get used to that!